# My boss sets unfair deadlines and expects everyone to work overtime

Tags: management, overtime, deadlines

I'm working at a small Startup. Recently I was put in charge of a new project with an also new client. The project itself is very interesting and I am excited to work on it.

But my boss, who negotiates things with the client, keeps setting deadlines which are way to short for the tasks at hand. Twice now I had three days to finished something that should have taken at the very least two weeks.

This was obviously done taking extreme shortcuts in order to show the client something. The developed application isn't dynamic, it just works for a very specific presentation.

He expects me to work 9-10 hours in the office plus working from home at night, on weekends, and work during the holidays.

He doesn't even have any skills regarding software engineering, so having him setting deadlines with the client is ridiculous. I've tried to argued against him but he blames for for delays. We are developing and showing things which are far from finished, and the deadlines keep getting worst.

What should I do? Should I leave this job and look for a new one? Or is there anything I can do to make things better?

Comment: If you don't want to work overtime, a startup is probably not the best place to work; **every** startup, by definition, is trying to do something ambitious with inadequate resources. Having said that, part of your job is to give the boss estimates of how much longer a task will take you, updated on a regular basis, so hecan adjust commitments or deadlines or manpower assignments to obtain the best results possible.

Comment: And additional to what @keshlam said, if you *are* keen to do something ambitious, and are willing to try to do it with inadequate resources, then please tell me you are at least getting some equity so you can share in the rewards if you *do* make the startup a success.

Comment: You have four choices: 1. Work tons of overtime, destroy your health and your family life, for no reward. 2. Negotiate significant rewards for working overtime, destroying your health etc. Paid overtime is always good. 3. Work the amount of hours you are paid for, probably 40 hours a week, and not a minute more. If this bankrupts the bosses business, then he had no business going into business. 4. Like (3) but look for a new job at the same time and don't feel bad for a jerk who wants to get rich at your expense.

Comment: I went through the exact same thing as you. I quit. Best decision I made in my whole life.

Answer (score 12):

> What should I do? Should I leave this job and look for a new one? Or is there anything I can do to make things better?

This sounds like a downward spiral. Your boss isn't competent enough in tech to have realistic deadlines and he's desperate for funding. So he's selling whatever the client wants.

This will only work if he has committed highly competent techs and listens to them.

My advice is if you can't handle the way things are done and the workload, start looking for a new job before it all falls to bits or you are replaced by someone who can. Startups with non technical people running them tend to be funding mines, the losers tend to be the techs who get chewed up and spat out, because the owners are not as interested in a final product as they are in funding their lifestyles by keeping clients happyish as long as they can. But this is only a generalisation. One of the symptoms of this is high pressure to get a presentation working, it's just a sales gimmick.

Don't leave the job and start looking, start looking before you leave.

Comment: Wish I could mark this _answer_ as favorite.